# Search is not work with the datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datatable

Dynamically update datatable from the php script.Below script we do with the AJAX.Here is My code search is not working with datatables. When i am users sAjaxSource data search is not working.With out using of the sAjaxSource search data.Can please provide the jsfiddle example.And the pagenation is not working.And page limit not working.Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Admin demo</title>
  <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "demo_page.css";
            @import "demo_table.css";               
   </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">   -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

var oTable = "";
    $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
    drawDataTable = function()
    {
      oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,      
        "sAjaxSource": 'reg_users.php',  
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sWidth": "200px"
        },
        null,
        null,
        null]
    })
        .columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [{
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "text"
        }, {
            type: "date-range"
        },{
            type: "text"
        }]
    });
   }

   // call datatable for the first time when page loads
   drawDataTable();
    oTable.fnClearTable();
   if (data.aaData.length)
      oTable.fnAddData(data.aaData);
   oTable.fnDraw();

    $('#example').on("click", "tr#dialog-confirm", function () {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        //' + $.trim(tableData[0]) + '

        var dynamicDialog = $('<div id="MyDialog" > <div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Amount</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" style="width:150px;"/><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="'+$.trim(tableData[0])+'" style="display:none;"/></div></div><div><div style="width:150px;float:left;">Password</div><div style="float:left;">:</div><div style="width:150px;float:left;"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:150px;"/></div></div></div>');
        dynamicDialog.dialog({
            title: "Admin chips adding",
            modal: true,
            height: 250,
            width: 400,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Yes",
                click: function () 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "html",
                        url: "Chips_AddedByAdmin.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            username: $.trim(tableData[0]),
                            amount: $('#amount').val(),
                            password: $('#password').val()
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#MyDialog').html('loading please wait...');
                        },
                        success: function (htmldata) {
                            //destroy existing datatable
                            $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                            //call datatable 
                            drawDataTable();

                            $('#MyDialog').html("You have successfully updated the database");
                            dynamicDialog.dialog("close");

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, {
                text: "No",
                click: function (e) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 150px;">UserName</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Email</th>
            <th style="width: 180px;">Created Date</th>
             <th style="width: 180px;">Real Chips</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 150px;">UserName</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Email</th>
            <th style="width: 180px;">Created Date</th>
             <th style="width: 180px;">Real Chips</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   

    </tbody>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

And this is reg_users.php

```
<?php 
        define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); // Your Database host
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'root'); // Your Database user name
        define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); // Your Database password
        define('DB_DATABASE', 'qwer'); // Your Database Name
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE); // Connection
        $sql = "SELECT nickname, email ,created_date_time,real_chips FROM users ";
        $rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        $str ="";

        $dataArr['aaData'] = Array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            $r = Array();
            foreach($row as $key=>$value){
                $r[] = "$value";
            }
            $dataArr['aaData'][] = $r;
        } 
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($dataArr);
       ?>
```

and this is Chips_AddedByAdmin.php

```
<?php
 require_once("configure.php");
    echo $nickname = $_POST['username'];
    echo $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    echo $password = $_POST['password'];

    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname ='admin' and password='$password';";
    $rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    if($numrows > 0)
    {

        echo $sql = "update users set real_chips=real_chips+'$amount' where nickname='$nickname';";
        $rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    }
?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> ... search is not working ... pagination is not working ... page limit not working ...

Well, where in your server-side code do you perform these actions?

I see no filtering, paging, or anything taking place here other than just fetching all records:

```
$sql = "SELECT nickname, email ,created_date_time,real_chips FROM users ";
$rs = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

With [server-side processing in DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), the JavaScript code sends additional parameters to the server to indicate a search string, page size, page number, etc.  It's then up to you to perform that logic in your queries server-side.  (Hence the term "server-side processing.")  See the DataTables documentation:

> With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server where an SQL engine (or similar) can perform these actions on the large data set (after all, that's what the database engine is designed for!). As such, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being made to get the required data.

There's an example of such a server-side script in PHP [here](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql).  For example, to perform the paging the script examines the supplies form values and modifies the SQL query:

```
/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}
```

In then goes on to perform similar query modifications for sorting, filtering, etc.

---

**Also**, as a side note, it looks like you're storing user passwords in plain text.  ***Never store user passwords in plain text***.  It is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.

Comment: With server-side processing in DataTables same thing done but the search is not working.Can you please run the above code check once.@David

Comment: @vamsikrishnareddy: No, I'm not going to run your code for you, nor do I have your database or your server configuration.  (You do realize I'm not actually using your computer, right?)  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for debugging.  However, *you* can run your code for you and examine its run-time behavior.  What you'll find is that DataTables is sending parameters to your server-side code for the purposes of sorting/filtering/paging, and your server-side code is simply ignoring those parameters.